# Why there's no thread suspension support in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

In Python [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html), it says

> The design of this module is loosely based on Java’s threading model, ... threads cannot be destroyed, stopped, suspended, resumed, or interrupted.

I could understand that the underlying mechanisms of Java and Python are different. But as there are individual solutions for both UNIX and Windows, why hasn't anyone written a single portable lib to support this? Or is there already one exist and I missed it?

Comment: There is no real support for thread suspension in Windows, I don't know about *nix. Perhaps you are thinking of `SuspendThread` but you are not supposed to use that function!

Comment: If there's no support in Windows, then why Java can do it? Is it because Java controls and manages all its thread in its JVM?

Comment: I don't know about Java, but what you say is certainly plausible.

Comment: @ziliangdotme: [Java thread suspension is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend()).  This is a poor man's synchronization which also happends to be totally unsafe as threads may be suspended at arbitrary points in their execution (including when they hold other synchronization resources).

Comment: but at least it can be done, right? I'm only talking about implementation, not safety..

Comment: OK. So does that mean people just prefer not to implement one?

Answer (score 3):

thread is not a unit for resource allocation, so before thread is closed, the thread should close all the resource it acquired (including file, socket, and other user-defined resources)

it you destroy the thread, all these resources will leak.

so you should not destroy a thread

for more information, check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: I'm not sure why someone voted this down, since it's right on the mark.  If you want a heavyweight thread of control that can be suspended and killed, use a process.  If you want low overhead, use threads - there are plenty of portable, standard synchronization primitives that threads can use to suspend and kill themselves.

Comment: @Dave: the same type of leaks may occur with processes (such as file locks, etc.).  Killing another thread of control should be a last resort, not your primary modus operandi.

Comment: well, I know destroying a thread is bad, but how about suspension? I think it may be useful in some situation.

Comment: Well, provide an example of where suspending a thread at a random point in its execution is preferable to having the thread wait at a known location for a known resource.

Comment: @ziliangdotme if the thread acquire a lock, pause this thread will make this lock locked forever, so how about use loop and check the pause flag before each loop

Answer (score 2):

Java *used to* support stopping, interrupting, and suspending threads, but the support was deprecated (but not yet, as of 1.6, outright removed):

> Why are Thread.suspend and Thread.resume deprecated?
>
> Thread.suspend is inherently deadlock-prone. If the target thread
>   holds a lock on the monitor protecting a critical system resource when
>   it is suspended, no thread can access this resource until the target
>   thread is resumed. If the thread that would resume the target thread
>   attempts to lock this monitor prior to calling resume, deadlock
>   results. Such deadlocks typically manifest themselves as "frozen"
>   processes.

from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html